# Kivy-Press a button on child Popup to change text of Label on parent Popup

Tags: python, kivy

The logic:

I press a button on a window, to open the first Popup;

I press a button on the first Popup, to open the second Popup;

I press a button on the second Popup, to call a function in the window class, to change text of a label on the first Popup.

Here is the sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
Builder.load_string("""
<FirstScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'open the first Popup'
            on_release: root.open_first_popup()
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<FirstPopup>:
    first_label: first_label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: first_label
            text: 'text on first Popup'
        Button:
            text: 'open second Popup'
            on_release: app.access_first_screen.open_second_popup()

<SecondPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: second_label
            text: 'text on second Popup'
        Button:
            text: 'change label text on first Popup'
            on_release: app.access_first_screen.change_label_text_on_first_popup()
        Button:
            text: 'close me to check if label text on first Popup has changed'
            on_release: root.close_me()

""")

class FirstPopup(Popup):
    pass

class SecondPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def close_me(self):
        self.dismiss()

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def open_first_popup(self):
        the_first_popup = FirstPopup()
        the_first_popup.open()

    def open_second_popup(self):
        the_second_popup = SecondPopup()
        the_second_popup.open()

    def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.access_first_screen.the_first_popup.first_label.text = 'change to me'

class Root(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        xx = FirstScreen(name='first screen')
        self.add_widget(xx)

class TestApp(App):
    access_first_screen = FirstScreen()
    access_first_popup = FirstPopup()
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Now the error is :

> AttributeError: 'FirstScreen' object has no attribute
>   'the_first_popup'

Then I tried with:

> ```
> def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):
>     app = App.get_running_app()
>     app.access_first_popup.first_label.text = 'change to me'
> ```

No error, but the text of Label on first Popup didn't change.
Then I tried with:

> ```
> def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):
>     app = App.get_running_app()
>     app.ids.first_label.text = 'change to me'
> ```

The error is:
AttributeError: 'TestApp' object has no attribute 'ids'

Then I tried:

> ```
> def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):
>     app = App.get_running_app()
>     self.the_first_popup.first_label.text = 'change to me'
> ```

The error is:
AttributeError: 'FirstScreen' object has no attribute 'the_first_popup'

I cannot make it work.

Comment: Define class attribute of type ObjectProperty in your Python script, e.g. the_first_popup = ObjectProperty(None), and the_second_popup = ObjectProperty(None).

Comment: Hi @ikolim , I define `the_first_popup = ObjectProperty(None)` in FirstScreen class, then tried some ways in `def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):`, the error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_label'`, still cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `open_first_popup()` method use `self.the_first_popup = FirstPopup()`.
That saves `the_first_popup` as an instance variable that you can access later as `self.the_first_popup` within the `FirstScreen` class.

So, here is a modified version of your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string("""
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<FirstScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'open the first Popup'
            on_release: root.open_first_popup()
        Button:
            text: 'Quit'

<FirstPopup>:
    first_label: first_label
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: first_label
            text: 'text on first Popup'
        Button:
            text: 'open second Popup'
            on_release: Factory.SecondPopup().open()

<SecondPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: second_label
            text: 'text on second Popup'
        Button:
            text: 'change label text on first Popup'
            on_release: app.root.get_screen("first screen").change_label_text_on_first_popup()
        Button:
            text: 'close me to check if label text on first Popup has changed'
            on_release: root.close_me()
""")

class FirstPopup(Popup):
    pass

class SecondPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def close_me(self):
        self.dismiss()

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def open_first_popup(self):
        self.the_first_popup = FirstPopup()
        self.the_first_popup.open()

    def open_second_popup(self):
        the_second_popup = SecondPopup()
        the_second_popup.open()

    def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):
        self.the_first_popup.first_label.text = 'change to me'

class Root(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        xx = FirstScreen(name='first screen')
        self.add_widget(xx)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I have eliminated the `access_first_screen`, because that just creates a new instance of `FirstScreen` that is unrelated to the one that appears in your GUI. That is why it always said:

```
'FirstScreen' object has no attribute 'the_first_popup'
```

because that new instance of `FirstScreen` did not have such an attribute (the instance in your GUI did have such an attribute). I have also eliminated `access_first_popup`.

I have also included my suggestions above.

Comment: @ John Anderson , Thanks reply, I change 'open_first_popup()' to    `def open_first_popup(self):
        self.the_first_popup = FirstPopup()
        self.the_first_popup.open()` and change `def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):` to `    def change_label_text_on_first_popup(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.access_first_screen.the_first_popup.first_label.text = 'change to me'` the error is still 'AttributeError: 'FirstScreen' object has no attribute 'the_first_popup''; if I use `
        self.the_first_popup.first_label.text = 'change to me'` , the error is same.

Comment: I have added complete modified code in my answer above.

Comment: Hi,@John Anderson. Now I know the issue is from how to bind the function to the button, not how is the function. I never think about this direction. I use `on_release: app.access_first_screen.change_label_text_on_first_popup()`, wrong; use your `on_release: app.root.get_screen("first screen").change_label_text_on_first_popup()`, correct, Interesting.